# Python merge two arrays on specific columns

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list, numpy

I have two sets/arrays/lists of the form

```
a = [(12, 14, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8), (16, 18, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3), (19, 22, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3)]
b = [(12, 14, 44, 12), (5, 4, 66, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
```

And I would like to find **c** which is a list of items from **b** found in **a** such that only the first two elements in the tuple need to match (ex 12 14). So in this case the answer **c** would be

```
c = [(12, 14, 44, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
```

I used nested loops however it is way too slow. Thanks

Comment: In your example you had a match for (using `numpy` indexing) `b[i,j]==a[i,]` where `j=0,1`, is this what you're asking or it was just coincidental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this `O(N)` time if you store all the unique two item tuples from `a` in a set first:

```
>>> keys = {x[:2] for x in a}
>>> [x for x in b if x[:2] in keys]
[(12, 14, 44, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
```

Note that if you're only trying to match items on the same index, then simply use `zip` with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [y for x, y in zip(a, b) if x[:2] == y[:2]]
[(12, 14, 44, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]

#Equivalent Numpy version:
>>> arr_a = np.array(a)
>>> arr_b = np.array(b)
>>> arr_b[(arr_b[:,:2] == arr_a[:,:2]).all(axis=1)]
array([[12, 14, 44, 12],
       [19, 22, 96, 45]])
```

Comment: How is this O(n)? The `x[:2] in keys` operation in the second case can in the worst case itself take o(n), causing the whole comprehension to be O(m*n)

Comment: @mu無 Sets provide `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary quick question, if I wanted to match [0th 1st] index in a with the [1st 2nd] index in b how would you amend this?

Comment: @IanDaz I guess it would become `[x for x in b if x[1:3] in keys]`

Comment: @IanDaz Then you can simply change the `if` condition to: `if x[1:3] in keys`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a list comprehension

```
>>> a = [(12, 14, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8), (16, 18, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3), (19, 22, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3)]
>>> b = [(12, 14, 44, 12), (5, 4, 66, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
>>> [item for item in b for checker in a if item[:2] == checker[:2]]
[(12, 14, 44, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
```

Comment: Edited your answer as OP seems to be wanting the b elements, not a.

Comment: @hagubear Thanks for notifying the same, have edited both the list comprehension and its output :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do with `numpy` if you're using `numpy`

```
In [49]: a = np.array([(12, 14, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8), (16, 18, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3), (19, 22, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3)])

In [50]: b = np.array([(12, 14, 44.0, 12.0), (5, 4, 66.0, 12.0), (19, 22, 96.0, 45.0)])

In [51]: print b[np.all(a[:,:2]==b[:,:2],1)]
[[ 12.  14.  44.  12.]
 [ 19.  22.  96.  45.]]
```

**How it works?**

```
In [52]: print a[:,:2]==b[:,:2]
[[ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]]
```

`np.all` takes an array of booleans and reduces using a *logical and* along the axis specified by the optional second argument (or using all the elements)

```
In [53]: print np.all(a[:,:2]==b[:,:2])
False

In [69]: print np.all(a[:,:2]==b[:,:2],1)
[ True False  True]

In [70]: print np.all(a[:,:2]==b[:,:2],0)
[False False]

In [71]:
```

in our case, of course, the right axis to use is `1`.

(ps: I must confess a bit of sloppiness in treating the types of your array values)

Comment: @SaulloCastro a simple and fast and _inscrutable_ numpy solution, eh!

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension

```
      >>> a = [(12, 14, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8), (16, 18, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3), (19, 22, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3)]
      >>> b = [(12, 14, 44, 12), (5, 4, 66, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
      >>> c=[j  for i in a for j in b  if i[:2]==j[:2]]
```

Output:

```
 [(12, 14, 44, 12), (19, 22, 96, 45)]
```